# Powermock - @SupressStaticInitializationFor is not working

Tags: java, powermock, maven-surefire-plugin, static-initialization

I have a class containing native methods and a static initializer which loads a dll and mocked it with powermock so that the the static initializer should be suppressed and the dll shouldn't be loaded.

The class looks like this:

```java
class UsbCommunication {

    static {
        //load some dll
    }

    public static native void nativeFunction();

}
```

Under windows the tests are successfully executed using maven (in eclipse as well as cmd).
But when I let our CI Server (a unix system) build the project all the tests get errors.

The test looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor
    ("com.printerStatus.UsbCommunication")
public class PrinterTest {
    //Test code
}
```

Whats confusing for me is the fact that I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError stating that the dll couldn't be loaded despite the fact that the static initializer should be suppressed.

**Versions:**

- Mockito: 1.9.0
- PowerMock: 1.4.12
- JDK: 1.7

Also I had to add this to the pom.xml as workaround for this problem: [PowerMock Issue](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=355)

```
<profile>
    <id>SplitVerifier</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

This is the stacktrace I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1828)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
    at de.kriegerit.tools.customPrinterStatusTools.CeSMLm.<clinit>(CeSMLm.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:111)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:51)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:100)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:58)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
    at de.kriegerit.tools.customPrinterStatusTools.PrinterInterfaceTest.setup(PrinterInterfaceTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:129)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:93)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
```

Is there any known issue or fix for this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are trying to load a Windows DLL on a Unix machine ;-)

Comment: Thats why I mocked it with PowerMock using the @SuppressStaticInitialization annontation to supress the part of the code that loads the dll.

Comment: @user2248239 That seems to fail then (could you verify that it works by some output in the static method?). Can't you mock the complete class `UsbCommunication` instead of only the method?

Comment: @user2248239 Don't there have to be a `@PrepareForTest` annotation also?

Comment: Ah you're right it fails to suppress the static initilization and tries to load the dll.

Comment: Sorry to revive this. Where you able to fix it? I have the same problem, having PrepareForTest and SuppressStaticInitializationFor. I think it might be the order of the lines.

Comment: The problem was that the static initializer was in a seperate abstract class and therefor not mocked by power mock.